# Continuity of trigonometric function with absolute values

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

I have to evaluate the continuity of this function
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\sin x + \dfrac{\sqrt{1-\cos2x}}{\sin x}, & x \neq 0 \\[6px]
\sqrt{2}, & x=0
\end{cases}
$$

For the function to be continuous we need $$ \lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = f(0) $$

We know that $ 1 - \cos2x = 2\sin^2x $ so we can rewrite the $ x \neq 0 $ part as: 
$$ \sin x + \frac{\sqrt{2\sin^2x}}{\sin x} = 
\sin x + \sqrt{2}\frac{\lvert\sin x\rvert}{\sin x}$$

Do I have to take cases here ($x \to 0^-$ and $x \to 0^+) $ for the $\lvert\sin x\rvert$ to find the limit I want, or can I assume that $ \sin x > 0 $?

---

**UPDATE**

Taking cases we have:
$$\lvert\sin x\rvert = 
\begin{cases}-\sin x, & x < 0 \\[4px]
\sin x, & x>0
\end{cases}
$$

so $$ \lim_{x \to 0^-}\sin x + \sqrt{2}\frac{-\sin x}{\sin x} = -\sqrt{2} $$

$$ \lim_{x \to 0^+}\sin x + \sqrt{2}\frac{\sin x}{\sin x} = \sqrt{2} $$

Can I assume something like this?

This [Wiki link](https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Absolute_value_of_sine_function) makes it clear that we can have $-{\sin x}$. Does it have anything to do with the fact that $ n \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Not doing the casework and simply evaluating the limit at $x=0$ should do the job.

Comment: @Tanuj i don't really understood your comment. If i take cases the limit left of 0 will give $ - \sqrt2 $ and the right  $ \sqrt2 $ , thus making the limit not definable and the function non continuous. Is something wrong with my thinking?

Comment: Just have a look at my answer .

Comment: Do not forget to accept the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assume $\sin x>0$; what's true is that, in a punctured neighborhood of $0$ one has $\lvert\sin x\rvert>0$, which is quite different.

Just observe that $\lvert-1\rvert>0$, but surely $-1$ is not greater than $0$.

---

Computing the limits from the left and from the right *isn't* necessary: what you need to see is whether $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=\sqrt{2}$. How to do this *may* involve computing the two limits.

You wouldn't need case work for
$$
g(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & x\ne0\\[4px] -1 & x=0\end{cases}
$$
would you?

In your particular case it is *convenient* to do it, because, as you show,
$$
\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x) \neq \lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)
$$
so the limit at $0$ doesn't even exist and therefore the function is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: So you say that my approach is ok for this particular problem but it is not always necessary to compute left/right limits?

Comment: @Segmentation Yes, that's it. The $g$ example was meant to clarify it.

Answer (score 1):

The case work isn't necessary , because if you see the graph of $y=\sin x$ , you would figure out that whether $x$ be $0^{+}$ or $0^{-}$ , the value of $\sin x $ would give you the value $0$.

Note that case work is necessary when you're getting different values for the same function from the right hand side and left hand side of the given point about which you've got to check the limit.

Comment: To make it clear. Because $|sinx|$ is always equal to $ 0 $ from either sides, we can assume that $ |sinx| = sinx $ ?

Comment: Yes , precisely !

Comment: If my answer helped , could you accept it ? It would be helpful for other people visiting this question.

Comment: $\frac{|sinx|}{sinx} \to -1\  for\  x \lt 0\ and\ \to +1\ for\  x\gt 0$

Comment: @herbsteinberg that's what i am trying to say. I updated my question with more information aboout this.